# How to auto text wrap labels according to image width using Image Magick?

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have been trying to annotate images using ImageMagick, which works well for short text that fits within the input image's width.  For example, to include a title "The Apollo Rocket Launch" to an image (e.g. rocket.png), I use the code below:

```
convert rocket.png -background Khaki  \
-font Helvetica -pointsize 30 label:'The Apollo Rocket Launch' \
+swap -gravity Center -append output.png";
```

The resulting image:

[image]

However, if the title is longer than the width of the image, then ImageMagick adds extra width to fit in the text (without any padding) as seen in the image below:

[image]

I would like wrap text to next line after taking in to account the width of input image.  One option is to manually enter \n characters in the text, which ImageMagick will automatically feed to next line.  But I would like it to  automatically adjust (be responsive) depending on image width without using \n characters. Is this possible in ImageMagick?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to this.  Only `caption` has the ability to word wrap automatically. [This link](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#caption) details it.  I just had to modify the code by using `caption` instead of `label`.  By specifying `-size` the caption is limited in width to the dimension specified.  Here I specify width 530px and don't specify height, which will be adjusted automatically.  I also specify `-gravity Center` before `caption` so that the text is automatically centered:

```
convert rocket.png -background Khaki  -size 530x \
-font Helvetica -pointsize 30 -gravity Center \
caption:'The Apollo Rocket Launch- A Mission Accomplished' \
+swap -gravity Center -append output.png
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: `+swap` is unknown option for GraphicsMagick v1.3.42, see [convert options](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/convert.html).